# Script compatible with Firefox, but not with other browsers...?

Tags: php, javascript, html, firefox, cross-browser

I'm having trouble making a web app work on more than 1 browser.

Here's the code for the FRONT-END page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Front-end: Invoice payment System</title>
        <link href="invoice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://mediodesign.ca/invoice_system/invoice/library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body id='content' name='content'>
        <div id="div_invoice_frontend_01"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "div_invoice_frontend_01" is calling the FRONT-END app.
It works in FIREFOX, but not in CHROME or SAFARI.

Might it be something in the PHP code?
If you need more info I will post the code...
Someone made this app for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Questions & Answers on Stack Overflow have to be useful for future visitors as well. A question in the format of "[Link] Help plz" becomes useless once the source code at the link changes.

Comment: The code has still a reference to a non-standard external script...

Comment: If it's a JavaScript problem we'll need to see the JavaScript. Could you [post a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem(s) to let us see what you're working with?

Comment: I never used  JSFiddle before...so forgive me if there's something missing : http://jsfiddle.net/453rH/

Comment: Evil `eval` all over the place O_o

Comment: What "eval" ? Might it be why it's not working on other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

there appears to be jQuery in your external script, but nothing in the HTML HEAD to allow jQuery to operate, i.e. jquery.js

Comment: I tried adding Jquery in the Head section, but still, nothing. Thanks though!